# Is this type of attribute value/function checking, a code smell in Python?

Tags: python, typechecking, duck-typing

*note*: This is [crossposted](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/142983/is-this-type-of-attribute-value-function-checking-a-code-smell-in-python) on CodeReview, as per recommendation

**Premise**: I have a class hierarchy (Python), where `tidy` is one of the methods. It removes nodes that are of type *ASTIgnore*, and rebinds the children of that node to its parent.

The target node cannot delete itself, and doesn't *see* its parent (for rebinding). Thus, the deletion of the target (of type ASTIgnore) would happen at its parent, where the parent *checks the type* of its children.

**Question**: How would this need to be implemented to reduce the code smell?

Which among these approaches is least bad, or are there other ones (see bottom)?

```
# A)
if child.nodetype == "ASTIgnore":

# B)
if child.isIgnored():

# C)
if child.isIgnoreType:

# D)
if isinstance(child, ASTIgnore):
```

Where, the classes and `tidy` looks like the below. I'll remove the redundancy, based on the cleanest implementation.

```
class ASTNode(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.nodetype = self.__class__.__name__
        self.isIgnoreType = False

    def isIgnored(self):
        return False

    def tidy(self):
        # Removes "Ignore" type/attribute nodes while maintaining hierarchy
        if self.children:
            for child in self.children:
                child.tidy()

            for i, child in reversed(list(enumerate(self.children))):
                #--------- Is this Bad? ----------
                if child.nodetype == "ASTIgnore":
                #------ --------------------------
                    if not child.children:
                        # leaf node deletion
                        self.children.pop(i)
                    else:
                        # target node deletion + hierarchy correction
                        grandkids = child.children
                        self.children[i:i+1] = grandkids


class ASTIgnore(ASTNode):
    def __init__(self):
        ASTNode.__init__()
        self.isIgnoreType = True

    def isIgnored(self):
        return True
```

**On matter of Duck Typing with a Tell-Not-Ask policy**:

I am new to Python, and would like to be a pythonic coder (and a better coder in general). Hence,

How do I *Duck Type* the above? Would checking the attribute value(`igIgnoreType`)/function(`isIgnored`) be considered *Duck Typing* if the attribute/function is never touched beyond object construction?

I do have another implementation, where `tidy` is overloaded in *Ignore* type nodes. **No more type checking**, but the parent still has to remove target child, and rebind grandkids. Here, the Ignore types return their children, which would be `[]` for leaf nodes. But, there is still a check on if the return was `None`. I am sure this is certainly *Duck Typing*, but is checking for `None` and code-replication, bad code?

```py
class ASTNode(object):
    def tidy(self):
        for i, child in reversed(list(enumerate(self.children))):
            grandkids = child.tidy()
            if grandkids is not None:
                self.children[i:i+1] = grandkids

        return None

class ASTIgnore(ASTNode):
    def tidy(self):
        for i, child in reversed(list(enumerate(self.children))):
            grandkids = child.tidy()
            if grandkids is not None:
                self.children[i:i+1] = grandkids

        return self.children
```

***_edit0***

Based on [Eric's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84128/eric-conner) vote, a `isIgnored()` function check implementation would look like

```py
def tidy(self):
    """
    Clean up useless nodes (ASTIgnore), and rebalance the tree
    Cleanup is done bottom-top
      in reverse order, so that the deletion/insertion doesn't become a pain
    """
    if self.children:
        # Only work on parents (non-leaf nodes)
        for i, child in reversed(list(enumerate(self.children))):
            # recurse, so as to ensure the grandkids are clean
            child.tidy()

            if child.isIgnored():
                grandkids = child.children
                self.children[i: i + 1] = grandkids
```

Comment: IMO `isIgnored()` makes your code the most understandable.  Having that extra signpost is easier for a reader than the second dense functions with repeated code.

Comment: Post that to Code Review: I'll get a chance to have an answer.

Comment: [Crossposted](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/142983/is-this-type-of-attribute-value-function-checking-a-code-smell-in-python) this on CodeReview. Added Eric's vote implementation.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE No, this question is not really a good fit for Code View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using the return value from the `tidy` method is a good way to pass information between your nodes. You're going to call `tidy` on each of your children anyway, so getting a return value that tells you what to do with that child makes the whole code simpler.

You can avoid repeating yourself by using `super` to call the base class's implementation from the derived class, and just changing the return value:

```
class ASTIgnore(ASTNode):
    def tidy(self):
        super().tidy() # called for the side-effects, return value is overridden
        return self.children
```

If you're using Python 2, where `super` is a little bit less magical than it is in Python 3, you'll need to use `super(ASTIgnore, self)` instead of `super()`.

Comment: This works very well for `tidy` method. I shall keep this technique in mind.!   **digression:**  Aside from that, I have a few other functions (`stringify`, `print_tree`, `emitPredicate`, `transform_ControlFlow`, etc) - which greatly benefit from the whole polymorphism aspect (base class gets the generic version, and some subclasses might overload it, i.e. the method operations really depend on the type that invokes it ). But, after reading about the Single Responsibility Principle, I am worried. Is this a gross violation of the SRP?

Comment: I don't think Single Responsibility Principle matters at this scale. It's mostly about larger scale design (e.g. module level) and doesn't need to be applied to every class. I'd guess all of your `ASTNode` subclasses are always going to be pretty tightly coupled to each other. That's not much of a problem for SRP since the classes will usually all get changed at once if there's any design change.

Comment: That's right! Most of the `ASTNode` subclasses are simply `pass`, while some extend the base with new data attributes. Attempting to separate the core methods from the classes would most certainly require some type of _type checking_ (say, `isIgnored()`, `isControl()`, etc). **___** I'll need to read up more about the whole SOLID thing and python idioms. Thanks! I have replaced explicit calls to the base class (`__init__`, `tidy`) with `super`.